# Angular Material multi select component with virtual-scroll

Tags: angular, select, angular-material, virtualscroll

I'm trying to create a custom multi select component, based on the angular-material select component (v10), with virtual-scroll and a custom search input inside the component's overlay.
I also added a `mat-select-trigger` element to display the number of selected items, instead of the default list of selected items.

The (almost fully working and without styling) example is available in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-virtual-scroll-x2iqvd?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

The issue I'm having is related with the displayed value of the selected items.

To replicate the issue you have to:

1. Search in the list of items (e.g.: `55`) and select an option (e.g. `item-55`)
2. Click outside of the overlay, to close it
3. As expected, the component will display `1 selected` and the item will be listed in the **Selected items** list below
4. Re-open the list, click in the search field `clear` button and then click outside the overlay, to close it again

The component will now display the `Items` placeholder, when it should be displaying `1 selected`, since the item is still in the **Selected items** list (and it's this list that it's used in the `mat-select-trigger` element).

Nonetheless, if you re-open the list and scroll to the selected item (`item-55`), it will be selected. If you then click outside the overlay to close it again, the correct value will be displayed (`1 selected`).

I understand it's a virtual-scroll related issue, but I've been unable to find a solution or workaround for this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!